# Good programming practices with centralizing variables

Tags: java, oop

Is it good programming practise, when dealing with multiple classes that need the same instance of variables, to create one central one?

```
chatWindow.variables.username = userField.getText();
```

For example:

1. I have a class with a set amount of variables
2. I have another class that needs the same variables
3. And another that needs the same variables as the first

So I have three classes that all use the same instance of variables

I only create the variable class instance using the first class (1)

I access these variables using classes (2), (3) through the class (1)

Example:
(while in classTwo()):

```
classOne.variableClass.VariableName = false;
```

**EDIT**: In basic form, my question is if it is OK to make a central 'variable class' and use other classes to access the same isntance of it through a main class.

I know my question is hard to understand but Im sure there is another, easier way. I tried passing the same instance of the first class through the constructor of the second and third classes but my solution some how seemed simpler.

Comment: can you give more details on your classes? It might be easier to help then

Comment: What do you mean by *needs the same variables*? Do you want to use those variables in other classes or just inherit them as properties of the other classes?

Comment: What you're asking about is called the **[Singleton (anti)pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/singleton-pattern.html)**. It's not recommended for use, see **[this](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/148108/why-is-global-state-so-evil)** question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This smells like [feature envy](http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/feature-envy)...  Sounds like something's wrong with your model when doing that.

If there's a group of variables that need to be changed in multiple classes, it probably should become an object (probably even an entity).  But you should consider that if you need to change these values in other classes, you might need to put some logic in that same class (to do validation checks and such).

Having an extra class just to keep variables is usually considered a code smell, called anemic domain.  However there are cases that do call for it, and it might be a matter of taste anyway.  In that case, your class is nothing but a glorified struct.

Answer (score 4):

It is best practice to use dependency injection and pass all the resources you need rather than having classes find what they want.

Using global variables is simpler to start with, but as your application grows and you want to use unit tests, these are a real pain as it becomes more difficult to manage and maintain these.

Answer (score 1):

It doesnt sound like you have segregated your classes quite properly. It can be ok for classes to modify other class variables but I would avoid having one place where you store mutable variables. That making things look like global variables which are very hard to manage and best avoided. See [here](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GlobalVariablesAreBad) for more details on that. Look up [Law of Dementer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter) as well which helps with keeping loose coupling in your program.

Answer (score 1):

Every problem has its own best compromises, you should ask yourself a series of questions.
Does (2) and (3) need ready only access to (1) or does they also need write access?

What you are actually doing (creating (2) and (3) from (1) seems good, builder pattern, you create istances that you never access directly)

If write access is needed should (2) be notified of changes made by (3) (or viceversa)?

Generally you should restrict as much as possible interactions from "sub-classes" (ideally is better trying to avoid having something shared, if is possible of course, but generally it is) so accessing them from within (1) seems also better solution than accessing (1) from (2) and (3).

That kind of restriction increase code maintenability, and removes/reduces problems like values changes notification, who owns who etc.

Basically if users need to warry only about (1) and all other stuff is handled internally you are already doing a good work (Pimpl idiom says nothing to you?)

You can also theath (2) and (3) like extensions to (1), so acting exactly like a strategy pattern. with the advantage that only (1) need to warry about istances, but if in future you need to extedn furtherly (1) you already have the strategy ready to go and you can update with minimal effort. (I always notice that multiple patterns are always present in every code you can write).

In the end you are the only who knows all code details, ask always yourself if you can improve code maintenability, easy of read etc, where possible upgrades are needed etc.

Comment: @Truth : that's not a Singleton, but just a class that references other classes, even a SceneGraph have similiar structure with multiple children referencing their parent.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you need due to the lack of examples, but maybe the Registry Pattern is what you need.

Basically, you create one static "global" class that holds all the variables you need throughout your application

```
public abstract final class VarRegistry {
    public static final String var1 = "val1";
    public static final int var2 = 2;
}
```

Now, in all the classes that need access to those variables, you can easily access and modify them:

```
VarRegistry.var1 = "test";
```

Wait just a second before you go off coding this: It's not very recommended to use "global" variables like this. It corrupts data encapsulation, because you never know how an when those variables are changed and by whom.

You maybe better off restructuring your program to support more secure patterns that properly enacpsule your data, e.g. Dependency Injection.

Comment: I would use an enum for a utility class. An abstract class can have sub-classes. ;)

Comment: Can't be `abstract final` I would use `public enum VarRegistry {;` which is final with a private constructor. ;)